# Spring MVC - loading data

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have filled database and one entity which uses 2 tables like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Product")
@SecondaryTable(name="B")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int idProduct;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(table="B",name="aaaa")
    private String aaa;
    @Column(table="B",name="bbbb")
    private String bbbb;
```

When I'm loading data from database table B is cleared, why?

I tried to change value in hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto from "create-drop" to "update" but I have an error like this:
 "Can not set int field com.packt.webstore.domain.Product.bbbb to null value".

I need to load and write data to database so which value shoud I set and how to fix this error?

EDIT: When I set @Column(name="bbb", nullable=true) is the same error.

Comment: "When I'm loading data from database table B is cleared, why?" --
I highly doubt that: `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop` means drop all tables and create new once when the application (hiberante) STARTS.

Comment: I need to load and write data to database so which value shoud I set?

Comment: I recommend to use `valid` or `update` but not `create-drop` because this would delete the database content with each application start.